# Specify the table type/storage engine in Doctrine 2

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search, doctrine-orm, myisam

So how can one specify the storage engine to use for a given entity in Doctrine 2?

I'm creating a table that needs a full text index and only the MyISAM storage engine supports full text indexing in MySQL.

As a side: it looks like Doctrine 2 doesn't support full text indexing out of the box?  Nor full text searches?  Is that correct?

Comment: It may not be "possible" without editing source: http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-972

Comment: Also (1.1): http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_1/zh/defining-models:indexes:special-indexes

Comment: @Jared I figured as much...  thanks for the ticket link.

Comment: A work-around from Benjamin Eberlei - http://groups.google.com/group/doctrine-user/browse_thread/thread/f1f270b9de878535

Answer (score 28):

I'm two years too late, but knowing this is important since it isn't documented for some reason,
we have been struggling to achieve this but this is the solution

```
/**
 * ReportData
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="reports_report_data",options={"engine":"MyISAM"})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Jac\ReportGeneratorBundle\Entity\ReportDataRepository")
 */
class ReportData
{
```

Comment: please only notice the 
options={"engine":"MyISAM"}

Comment: Thanks!, don't know why this isn't marked as the answer, weird.

Answer (score 7):

## Update:

See the comment about adding "@Table(name="table_name",options={"engine"="MyISAM"})" , it is the better answer.

======= Original Below ===========

This is untested code aimed to help you get to an answer, you will need to read a lot of Doctrine2 code to figure out what you want though. I spent about 30mins reading code and couldnt find a way to push the $options array through the ORM layer to this DBAL layer function.

check out Doctrine/DBAL/Platforms/MySQLPlatform.php

```
427         // get the type of the table
428         if (isset($options['engine'])) {
429             $optionStrings[] = 'ENGINE = ' . $options['engine'];
430         } else {
431             // default to innodb
432             $optionStrings[] = 'ENGINE = InnoDB';
433         }
```

try hard coding [what engine](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/storage-engines.html) want in there. It will almost certainly break stuff though (eg, foreign keys [dont work in MyISAM](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/myisam-storage-engine.html))

Comment: You can set this for a table using `@Table(name="table_name",options={"engine"="MyISAM"})`

Comment: @PaulJacobse you should post this as an answer

Answer (score 3):

If you're using doctrine2 migrations ..

```
$table = $schema->createTable('user');
$table->addColumn('id', 'integer');
$table->addOption('engine' , 'MyISAM');
$table->setPrimaryKey(array('id'));
```