# Delete all foreign keys in mysql database

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I can see that there are some questions [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13733281/drop-all-foreign-keys-in-mysql-database),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14546477/delete-all-foreign-keys-in-databasemysql)] that already ask for this, but where the solution didn't contain a complete SQL script to do this task.
I have a situation where it would be very helpful to delete all foreign keys using SQL only.
Currently I'm trying to solve this with a stored procedure and a cursor as follows:

```
-- No automatic commits:
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS removeConstraints;
-- Magic to happen soon:
DELIMITER |
CREATE PROCEDURE removeConstraints()
BEGIN
  SET AUTOCOMMIT=0;
  SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
  -- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cursors.html
  -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745165/looping-over-result-sets-in-mysql
  -- https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/cursor-overview/
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
  DECLARE s VARCHAR(1024) DEFAULT '';
  DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ',TABLE_NAME, ' DROP FOREIGN KEY ', CONSTRAINT_NAME, ';')
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Key_COLUMN_USAGE
    WHERE REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME IS NOT NULL;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

  OPEN cur;

  read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH cur INTO s;
    IF done THEN
      LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;
    PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
  END LOOP;

  CLOSE cur;

  SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
  COMMIT;
  SET AUTOCOMMIT=1;
END |
DELIMITER ;
-- Do magic:
CALL removeConstraints();
-- Cleanup:
DROP PROCEDURE removeConstraints;
```

Sadly this produces the following error message:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 5: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
  DECLARE s VARCHAR(1024) DEFAULT '';
  DECLARE ' at line 8
```

---

With the input from [Ravinder Reddy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30618741/448591) I've now updated the `DECLARE` parts right after the `BEGIN` to look like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE removeConstraints()
BEGIN
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
  DECLARE s VARCHAR(1024) DEFAULT '';
  DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR 
          SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ',TABLE_NAME,' DROP FOREIGN KEY ',CONSTRAINT_NAME,';')
          FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Key_COLUMN_USAGE
          WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA=DATABASE()
          AND REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME IS NOT NULL;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

  SET AUTOCOMMIT=0;
  SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
```

but when I try to execute the procedure I still get an error:

```
  MariaDB [v4]> CALL removeConstraints();
  ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL' at line 1
```

I've also tried to use a different `SELECT` statement like:

```
SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ',TABLE_NAME,' DROP FOREIGN KEY ',CONSTRAINT_NAME,';')
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Key_COLUMN_USAGE
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA=DATABASE()
AND CONSTRAINT_NAME != 'PRIMARY'
AND CONSTRAINT_NAME IS NOT NULL
AND TABLE_NAME IS NOT NULL;
```

…but it didn't help.

---

I've got it working now by changing the code so that the `CONCAT` happens later.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS removeConstraints;
-- Magic to happen soon:
DELIMITER |
CREATE PROCEDURE removeConstraints()
BEGIN
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
  DECLARE tName VARCHAR(64);
  DECLARE cName VARCHAR(64);
  DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR 
          SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME, CONSTRAINT_NAME
          FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Key_COLUMN_USAGE
          WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA=DATABASE()
          AND REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME IS NOT NULL;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

  SET AUTOCOMMIT=0;
  SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

  OPEN cur;

  read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH cur INTO tName, cName;
    IF done THEN
      LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;
    SET @sql = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ',tName,' DROP FOREIGN KEY ',cName,';');
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
  END LOOP;

  CLOSE cur;

  SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
  COMMIT;
  SET AUTOCOMMIT=1;
END |
DELIMITER ;
-- Do magic:
CALL removeConstraints();
-- Cleanup:
DROP PROCEDURE removeConstraints;
```

Comment: OK, I'm under the impression that it might have to do with the ```PREPARE``` statement. Because if I use ```PREPARE stmt FROM 'SELECT "TEST";';``` all goes well o.O

Comment: The `near 'NULL'` problem was probably due to `@s` never being set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All `DECLARE` statements must be on top in a `BEGIN` - `END` block.

And all other statements should follow them.

In your code, you have `SET` statements defined before `DECLARE` statements.
Move those statements to below of `DECLARE` statements.

**Sample**:

```
  -- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cursors.html
  -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745165/looping-over-result-sets-in-mysql
  -- https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/cursor-overview/
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
  DECLARE s VARCHAR(1024) DEFAULT '';
  DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR 
          SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ',TABLE_NAME,' DROP FOREIGN KEY ',CONSTRAINT_NAME,';')
            FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Key_COLUMN_USAGE
           WHERE REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME IS NOT NULL;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

  SET AUTOCOMMIT=0;
  SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
```

**Document Reference**:

[***DECLARE Syntax***](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/declare.html)

> *`DECLARE`* is permitted only inside a *`BEGIN ... END`* compound statement
>   and must be at its start, before any other statements.
>
> Declarations must follow a certain order. Cursor declarations must
>   appear before handler declarations. Variable and condition
>   declarations must appear before cursor or handler declarations

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm under the impression that it already helped me some of the way, just not all of it. Also I feel like I'm handling the debugging a bit clumsy…